# Replace Text within HTML-Tags, except within HTML-Attributes (regular expression)

Tags: html, swift, regex, replace, swiftsoup

I'm trying to find some text regex matches in a HTML string and replace that matches with a special markup. In the example string below, I would like to find the word `swiftsoup`, and replace it with `<b>swiftsoup</b>`, but exclude all matches in all attributes like `id="swiftsoup"` or in `href` url.

```html
// example string
<p>swiftsoup is awesome, but I don't know how to solve with <a id="swiftsoup" href="https://github.com/scinfu/swiftsoup">swiftsoup</a> or other. Love swiftsoup even so.</p>
```

The following SwiftSoup Code doesn't work of course, because `ownText()` to `text()` are not a mutating functions and cannot handle the unused result of `replacingOccurrences(of:with:)`:

```swift
let h = #"<p>swiftsoup is awesome, but I don't know how to solve with <a id="swiftsoup" href="https://github.com/scinfu/swiftsoup">swiftsoup</a> or other. Love swiftsoup even so.</p>"#

let p = try! SwiftSoup.parse(h).select("p").first()!

p.ownText().replacingOccurrences(of: "swiftsoup", with: "<b>swiftsoup</b>")
           ^~~~~~
```

Maybe a regular expression with `html()` could be help, but I don't know how to preserve the matches inside of attribute values:

```swift
extension String {
    func markUpSwiftSoup() -> String {
        var selfResult = self
        let selfAsNSString = self as NSString

        if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "swiftsoup") {

            let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: selfAsNSString.length)
            regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: range).forEach {

                let match = selfAsNSString.substring(with: $0.range)
                selfResult = selfResult.replacingOccurrences(of: match, with: "<b>\(match)</b>")
            }

            return selfResult

        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}

var pHTML = try! p.html()
p.html(pHTML.markUpSwiftSoup())
```

The **Result I try to get** is that:

```html
<p><b>swiftsoup</b> is awesome, but I don't know how to solve with <a id="swiftsoup" href="https://github.com/scinfu/swiftsoup"><b>swiftsoup</b></a> or other. Love <b>swiftsoup</b> even so.</p>
```

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: Would it be realistic to just check if your keyword, "swiftsoup" in this case, has a space before or after it before adding the tags?

Comment: I'm really wondering if it would make more sense to whitelist certain instances of your keyword or to blacklist other cases. (Would the keyword as an `id` be more common than the keyword as a regular substring?)

Comment: The example above with search-string "swiftsoup" is just simplified to explain my question better! In the real cases I search for words with a specific pattern, whose have to be marked up. `id` and `href` are also just examples for random attributes, where the search pattern matches with their values like within tags. It can be any other attributes. The main important thing is to do not replace matches in attribute values, only replace matches within tags, like `<tag attr="no replace">replace</tag>`